# What is the "loaded resistor" for ultrasonic receivers?

Tags: resistors, ultrasound

I have an ultrasonic receiver (datasheet available [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/81173.pdf)). On page 2, there are two graphs plotting sensitivity variation and center frequency shift versus "loaded resistor":

[image]

What does "loaded resistor" exactly mean in this context?

Comment: They must mean "load resistor". Operating the transducer as a microphone, it means the input impedance of the mic amplifier. So you need 39k or more input impedance for highest sensitivity.

Comment: So if I don't connect an amplifier (say I just look at the signal on a scope), I shouldn't expect it to work?

Comment: Should work just fine. The scope input impedance is probably 1 Megohm (use a x1 probe) - as I said, more than 39k. Just bear in mind that -60db ref 1V is 1 mv so there might not be much to see. What's the highest sensitivity range on your scope?

Comment: An oscilloscope is designed for speed not sensitivity, so as @Brian points out, you may need/want a pre-amp or amplified (Active) probe for your scope in this situation -- but it isn't because the input impedance is "wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess they mean *load* resistor, not *loaded* resistor.

A load resistor is like a dummy. You can use it to test a power supply, antenna tuner, .... Instead of the device you'd connect normally to the device you want to test, you connect a dummy load or load resistor to it, so that if something goes wrong, you mess up the dummy and not the real device.

About your datasheet: the manufacturer did some tests with his device and a dummy load or load resistor. The diagrams give explanation on that.